# Serving static files from local server when internet is down

Tags: python, django

I am running a Django app on a dedicated server on company LAN. Initially I setup all static files to be served either from CDN or my S3 bucket. What happens if the company's internet goes down? I know that static files are saved in the cache on users' computers, but let's say they hard-reload it or the cache gets cleaned some other way. If i put both paths in my settings, will the server only serve static files from local drive if the first link isn't working? What is the correct approach to this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
  crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: "What is the correct approach to this?"—that depends entirely on your use case. In many situations, when the Internet goes down stuff breaks and that may be fine. If you want to self-host you're welcome to, but _that_ can go down too and now it may be _your_ job to fix it. Tradeoffs.

Comment: What I mean is, if i set it up like in the snippet above, with both links available, where will they be accesed from by the end-user? CDN or local server?

Comment: Oh, you've got the same file in there twice? Then the user's browser will try to load _both_. It has no way to know that those files are supposed to be the same. I'm not sure what the value is here, though. It seems overly complicated, adds HTTP requests, and increases bandwidth usage. Are you dealing with frequent Internet outages?

Comment: So, it's a bad idea then, right? What would be a corect way to have the file loaded from internet first, and only if it fails, load from local?

Comment: I wouldn't do that at all. Pick one or the other.

Comment: I only have internet links now. I was just thinking, in case of an outage (and no, it's not common) if i should have a backup. But it's not really that big a deal. More curious what's the professioanl approach to it.

Comment: professional approach probably could be router/proxy/balancer (hardware) which can redirect all traffic to other computer. But it would be local hardware in company which normally gives access to internet.

Comment: @Viktor If you want to download any files you may try embedding into your HTML JavaScript-based downloader [like this one](http://danml.com/download.html), it supports setting callbacks on success and failure. You may set failure callback to do download from your local server. If you hosted JS/CSS on your CDN then for falling back you may use [another library](http://fallback.io/), it allows to load JS/CSS from your server on failure.

Comment: @Arty Thanks. That looks like a good option.